# Jquery .each not working for first row from the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using jquery .each to loop the values and push in JSON. it is working for all the rows leaving the first row.

```
for (j = 0; j < parsedResult.length; j++) {
   var pack_id = parsedResult[j].pack_id;
   var pack_dsc = parsedResult[j].pack_dsc;
   var pack_base_amount = parsedResult[j].pack_base_prc;
   var pack_tax_amount = parsedResult[j].pack_tax_amt;
   var pack_grand_total = parsedResult[j].pack_grand_total;

   row += "<span id='single_pack_details'><span id='pack_id' class='hidden'>" + pack_id + "</span><b>Pack description: </b><span id='pack_dsc'>" + pack_dsc + "</span><b>Pack Amount:</b> &#8377; <span id='pack_grand_total'>" + pack_grand_total + "</span></div><span class='hidden' id='pack_base_amount'>" + pack_base_amount + "</span><span class='hidden' id='pack_tax_amount'>" + pack_tax_amount + "</span></span>";
                    }
```

Below is where i trying to put it in a loop and pushing to pack_details object

```
$(this).closest("tr").find('#single_pack_details').each(function () {
var obj = {
pack_id: $(this).closest("span").find("#pack_id").text(),
pack_dsc: $(this).closest("span").find("#pack_dsc").text(),
pack_grand_total: $(this).closest("span").find("#pack_grand_total").text(),
pack_base_amount: $(this).closest("span").find("#pack_base_amount").text(),
pack_tax_amount: $(this).closest("span").find("#pack_tax_amount").text()
}
pack_details.push(obj);
```

Comment: Ids have to be **unique**

Comment: yea but how it is working for 2nd and 3rd row of my table? @Andreas

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: Not with duplicated ids...